# How to handle page navigation and incoming links on entirely ajax site?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I am creating an entirely ajax site and one of the issues is that you can't provide links to direct pages as a result. I made it so that it appends the name of the page into the url every time you click an ajax link, but now I need a php script in my main file that gets run EVERY time you click to load a page. This will check to see if any of the get variables are set and redirect you to the proper page. For example if I give you this link `http://techxpertschico/techxperts/repair` then it should be able to load the appropriate content into the page rather than taking you to the homepage. I suspect that this will look similar to the code below. I just don't know how to make the ajax request happen on the isset request. I need help figuring out what to add to my php script.

```
<?php
if(isset($_GET['notsurewhatgoeshere'])) { 
    //load the appropriate page using jquery
}
?>
```

Here is the code for the ajax request

```
 $('.ajaxAnchor').on('click', function (event){ 
    event.preventDefault(); 
    $('a .top').css({'background' : 'transparent'});
    $('a .top').children().css({'background' : 'transparent'});
    $(this).children().css({'background' : '#EEEEEE'});
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    var shortened = url.substring(0,url.length - 5);
    History.pushState({state:1}, shortened, shortened);
    $.get(url, function(data) {
        $('section.center').html(data);
    });
});
```

If you need to see additional code please let me know and I will add it. Thanks!

Comment: This is called a PHP Framework/Router in essence. You can route every page request no matter the /sub/dir/pattern/article/number and make it hit index.php, or any file of your choosing. From there, you create routes based on the url criteria. Rolling your own isn't too difficult, but its been done a million times. Look for PHP Framework, router. I'll post the .htaccess need to make everything land on a single page.

Comment: codeManiak, will the URl change at all ?? i mean users will ever see a different address ? i mean assuming what you wrote, the URL wouldnt ever change ?Like in the address bar ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place this .htaccess file in the root of your website, and your server is configured properly, it will make any and all url links land on index.php. From there you can inspect the requested URL and decide where to go.

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

Inside Index.php, you can inspect the $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] element to break up the requested URL.

This is somewhat minimal and doesn't 100% answer your question, but the scope of what you want to do is a little bigger than a single answer.

Comment: It should also be noted that when using .htaccess in this way, it is usually a good idea to use absolute paths for your links, including those in `<head>`.  Relative paths get tricky when you start passing variables in a manner that appears to the browser to be directories.

Comment: So I created a file called index.htaccess and put that exact code into it and I'm not seeing it make any and all url links land on index.php.

Comment: Hey Code, not index.htaccess, just .htaccess. Seems weird I know, but that is a legit file.

Comment: I see that now thanks! I'm still having some slight issues though. I don't know if I need to specify something inside of the code you gave me because I am getting a new error when you visit http://techxpertschico.com/repair `no input file specified`

Comment: I use Rottingham's solution here often, with the following change.  I replace the last line with `RewriteRule (.*) index.php?parameters=$1 [L,QSA]`.  Now, when you would navigate to, say, `http://techxpertschico.com/foo/bar`, you will have a new parameter at `$_GET['parameters']` containing the string `'foo/bar'`, and you can parse that as you please, to direct your application to the right content.  Also note, that `[L,QSA]` will preserve any other parameters you send in the url.

Comment: I think this is exactly what I need! I'll check back in soon

Answer (score -1):

Don't quite understand your question, but anyhow, a javascript function can be triggered by certain event, by page onload, i.e 
or button onclick(); i.e. Click me. 
In myFunction(){ you can write Ajax function to perform post/get. Inside javascript function, you can reload the page by using                      document.location.href = 'your new http://';